# Capture only TCP SYN-ACK packets with tcpdump

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, tcpdump

I'm trying to capture only TCP SYN-ACK packets, i.e. with both SYN and ACK bits set with:

```
tcpdump -vvvni eth0 tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn and tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-ack
```

but it gives such error:

```
tcpdump: expression rejects all packets
```

I still can't figure out if there is a way to do it through the [*`tcpdump`*](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html).

By the way, I tried to capture packets with just SYN flag set expecting there will be SYN-ACKs too (because there is no contradiction here), but there were only pure SYN packets (with only SYN bit set). So I need some way to see only SYN-ACKs, or SYNs and SYN-ACKs.

P.S. it is about regular TCP over IPv4.

Comment: Have you considered using a Packet Sniffer?  Start with Wire Shark.  I use Comm View (Tamosoft) and I can see such packets.

Comment: @John Unfortunately I can't install additional soft to this particular VM. Btw is there a way to use it in terminal?

Comment: What you are looking for is not just simple. I looked at tcpdump and did not see anything. What you want is more suited to a packet sniffer.

Comment: @John `tcpdump` is a packet sniffer too. I don't see any complexity about logical filtering packets by bits set in header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on looking at the [pcap-filter](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) man page and especially the examples at the end I would suggest that the correct filter syntax to match packets which have at least both SYN and ACK are set would be:

```
tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack) == tcp-syn|tcp-ack
```

Your filter expression instead tried to match packets where the flags are **equal** to SYN and **equal** to ACK at the same time which does not work since it cannot be equal to both at the same time, but it can only **contain** both flags.

If you are interested in matching packets where the flags are equal to SYN+ACK and no other flags are set then you can also use the simpler syntax:

```
tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn|tcp-ack
```

Comment: There is a need in quotes in case of `syntax error near unexpected token '=='`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @red0ct: Please make sure to properly quote the expression on the shell since it contain characters which have a special meaning for the shell. I.e. `tcpdump -i eth0 -n 'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack) == tcp-syn|tcp-ack'`. *"There is a need in quotes"* - only if you use the filter syntax within a command on the shell. The filter itself does not need the quotes, the shell does.